# Discord Bot Join Voice Channel

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want my Discord bot to join Voice Channel, but I am running into a problem that whenever I want it to join VC nothing happens - even no errors. I have tried other solutions from SO/Git but none of them worked for me (one of them below):

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot something.

Line 4 needs to be

```
channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already solved your issue, but I'll show you how I solved it anyway, especially if you ever use `@client.event`.

I'm not sure if this will work, but have a try.
Firstly, I went into my terminal and used `pip install PyNaCl`.
Then I used `await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()`

From there, you can play your audio file. Though first, I'd install `ffmpeg` just in case. Just keep this in mind, but anyways, congratulations on finding a solution!